# Group by Certain Age Group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column of age values that I need to group by in columns.

For example in this dataframe I have:

[image: age]

and would like to get to:

[image]

I did this to try to filtering it out and get the data but its returning nothing.

```
data_df = df[df['Age'] <= 30]
data_df
```

and its not working correctly and I got an error.

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert values of column to numeric by remove `+`, then binning by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and last create indicators by [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with append to original `DataFrame`:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(str).str.strip('+').astype(int)

df  = df.join(pd.get_dummies(pd.cut(df['Age'],
                           bins=(0,18,25,29,50,np.inf), 
                           labels=['Under 18','19_to_25','26_to_29','30_to_50','Over 50'])))
print (df)
    Age  Under 18  19_to_25  26_to_29  30_to_50  Over 50
0    12         1         0         0         0        0
1    13         1         0         0         0        0
2    14         1         0         0         0        0
3    18         1         0         0         0        0
4    20         0         1         0         0        0
5    25         0         1         0         0        0
6    30         0         0         0         1        0
7    40         0         0         0         1        0
8    50         0         0         0         1        0
9    60         0         0         0         0        1
10   70         0         0         0         0        1
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like magic!