# Multiple column in a single boxplot using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, boxplot

In relation with this [Group by Certain Age Group in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276011/group-by-certain-age-group-in-pandas)

I am trying to group them in a single boxplot like this.
[image]

But I encountered an issue while using this code.

```
cn = ['AgeUnder18', 'Age19to25', 'Age26to29']
sns.boxplot(x=cn, y='AveMonthSpend', data=df)
```

Error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
> a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the dataframe to ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cn = ['AgeUnder18', 'Age19to25', 'Age26to29']
df = pd.DataFrame({age_group: np.random.uniform(45, 65, 7) for age_group in cn})
df_melted = df.melt(value_vars=cn, value_name='AveMonthSpend', var_name='Age Bin')
sns.boxplot(y='Age Bin', x='AveMonthSpend', data=df_melted, palette='Greys')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot from multiple columns]

This supposes the original dataframe looks like:

```py
Out[10]: 
   AgeUnder18  Age19to25  Age26to29
0   64.980248  64.673755  56.489776
1   59.858895  48.921889  62.877826
2   62.357871  51.599347  55.651448
3   47.206124  45.817266  52.893839
4   57.627501  51.820863  59.616511
5   61.999523  63.443241  45.919390
6   56.616062  48.353018  46.282314
```